# Office workstations connected to one TV via ethernet

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv, kvm-switch

In my office, the developers are often have to stand up and go to each-other to take a look on the screen and its content. I wish to make this a bit easier and faster for them. There is a wall located quite in the center and within normal usage for all of the developers. I was thinking about putting a 128cm FullHD LED TV for them, so they can show each-other whatever they want. Now here comes the real kicker: How do I share the screen between 8 computers including Fedora Workstations, Windows 10 and Mac OS X computers?

I was thinking about a KVM Switch with HDMI compatibility but then I've realized, that would be extremely expensive.

- I would have to buy a HDMI splitter for each computer
- I would have to buy a HDMI to Ethernet adapter for each computer
- Then buy a HDMI KVM switch with a remote controller

But what if I just get a HDMI splitter for each computer and get a TV with this many HDMI plugs and then I can simpply change computer just by switching channel on the TV. Do you guys know a TV with 8-10 HDMI plugs? :D

Or if not, then how would you solve this?

Comment: Many chat tools such as Skype have screen sharing or window sharing abilities.  Have you considered using any of them? I know this works on Windows, but have no idea about Linux or MacOS

Comment: The cheapest solution is probably going to be based on VNC (or similar) and a small £100 "micro" PC connected to the TV. Any TV with that many inputs is likely to cost more than any possible time saving you are likely to get from using it.

Comment: Hmmm, tha micro-PC version sounds good, but how would you connect the workstations screen to it via VNC? It supposed to work the other way, so the TV needs to connect to the client then.

Answer (score 2):

Plug in a Chromecast so the PCs, Chromebooks, and Android devices can cast their screens to the shared TV via Miracast (or whatever protocol Chromecast uses), and plug in an Apple TV (4th gen or later) so the Macs and iOS devices can do the same via AirPlay Screen Mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple options that present themselves and don't need some expensive AV setup. What they do need though is some kind of [single PC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Maxesla-Frequency-x5-Z8350-Processor-Bluetooth/dp/B06XNRG5PX) connected to your TV.

1. Many chat tools such as Skype have screen sharing or window sharing abilities. I know this works on Windows, but have no idea about Linux or MacOS but would be surprised if they don't work. You would then have to have a special Skype profile that you can share your screens at.
2. Install VNC (or some similar software) on each of the desktop PCs and connect to your desktop PCs *from* the TV. The problem here is people knowing which PCs are theirs in order to connect to.

I'm suggesting a small PC connected to the TV because the AV setup for an entire office connected to one TV are somewhat difficult, while the networking setup is quite simple by comparison as you will already have an existing network.

The maximum workable length of an HDMI cable is (depending on who you speak to) 25 or 50 feet, depending on cable quality this could be much less and how they are routed could mean that they are far too short.  I've never seen a TV with more than 3 HDMI inputs, but you could conceivably get a [3 way HDMI switcher](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GANA-Intelligent-Switcher-Splitter-Supported-hdmi-switch-3-in1/dp/B071P3L748) and so connect more inputs to the TV.

To me it is a much simpler solution to go with a ["micro" PC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Maxesla-Frequency-x5-Z8350-Processor-Bluetooth/dp/B06XNRG5PX) type device and share a screen *at* it because

- it is simply 1 single networking run that you need to do and potentially a bunch of "Daves Machine", "Bills PC", etc. VNC profile links, or a "Display PC" Skype profile to share a screen at.
- 8 or more HDMI runs will mean you spend an age dragging HDMI cables, labelling them and the switches up, and having some kind chart as to what input you need on the TV and what switches need to be on which boxes.
- The networking method is easily expandable to however machines are on your network.  If you get new devs then it is a simple matter to install the requisite software and set up a new profile on the "TV".
- If someone leaves, moves, or otherwise changes their setup then it means not only changing network setup but potentially digging up and re-routing the HDMI cable.
- It could be embarrassing if someone left a "screen"connected to the TV and someone turns on the TV and sees some personal or private content...
- by comparison it is easier to "disconnect" a network shared screen than go rummaging through the screen setup and disconnect procedure for whatever OS you are using.